# Check if a plot is displayed using pinescript

Tags: plot, pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, technical-indicator

I have an indicator with 2 moving averages lines, and for each MA line I put a label with the price corresponding to that MA, the problem is the following:

I want to hide a MA line and it's price label, from the configuration window it hides the MA line, but It does not hide the label with the price.

Is there a way to check if the moving average is plotted or not using pinescript?

Is possible to know the value of that checkbox from the image corresponding to the MA red line?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check that.

As a workaround, you can set you plot's `editable` property to `false` and use a user input instead to enable/disable the plot. This way you can also display your label or not based on the user input.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

plot_sma = input.bool(true, "Plot SMA 20")

sma_20 = ta.sma(close, 20)
plot(sma_20, "SMA 20", color.white, editable=false, display=plot_sma ? display.all : display.none)

if (plot_sma)
    lbl = label.new(bar_index + 1, high, str.tostring(sma_20, format.mintick), color=color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor=color.white)
    label.delete(lbl[1])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Switch using an expression", "", true)

string maType = input.string("EMA", "MA type", options = ["EMA", "SMA", "RMA", "WMA"])
int maLength = input.int(10, "MA length", minval = 2)

float ma = switch maType
    "EMA" => ta.ema(close, maLength)
    "SMA" => ta.sma(close, maLength)
    "RMA" => ta.rma(close, maLength)
    "WMA" => ta.wma(close, maLength)
    =>
        runtime.error("No matching MA type found.")
        float(na)

plot(ma)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).